# How can i develop and publish app after it has been transferred to another user

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, app-transfer

I developed ios application for some company. I have been successfully publishing app until APPLE rejected it. Do to new APPLE guidelines developers can't anymore upload applications for their clients. As I understood I need to transfer my app to the client.
The question now is how can I still maintain and develop it for client/company. What do I or my client needs to do in order to upload ipa file. I read some forums but I can't find any good explanation how to do it.

Comment: Your client can just give you access to their account and you can upload the app on their account.

Comment: As Administrator or basic member?

Comment: Developer at least, as a member you can not upload apps.

Comment: What about certificates? I need to create new certificates?

Comment: Yes you should have their certificates, you can have 2 distribution certificates in your account. You can either create on or have the company mail you theirs.

Comment: @Vitali Ask your client to add you as an admin, so that you can create the certificates and upload the apps.